# Convert Column values into row values with new row headers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

**Starting table**

```
Col1|col2|col3
---------------
1   |EDTU|Value1
2   |EDTP|Value2
3   |aaaa|value3
4   |bbbb|value4
5   |cccc|value5
```

I only need values for `EDTU` and `EDTP` in below format with new row header

**Expected result:**

```
XXXX  |YYYY
----------
value1|value2
```

Note :- using where clause if `col2 = 'EDTU'` we get `Value1`.

Comment: Pivot is what you are looking for but your sample table has insufficient data.  What tells you that two particular EDTU and EDTP values are related to each other?

Comment: Col 2 here refers to kind of setting names, Col 3 here refers to the value of each setting name. My actual requirement is I have 4 databases in which starting table is common so are the setting names but the values can be different in each database, so i want to get all of them in a single table and try to find a match to execute code against the result obtained. So before going for each database table, I want to first try it in one database. Requesting your suggestions/help

Comment: Thanks @Randi for putting the question in a clear way :) :)

Comment: @NishantSinku no problem! Welcome to dba.se! Consider taking [the tour](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour) and reading up on asking [minimal, verifyable and complete examples](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) for future questions. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming then, that you are going to add (or derive) another column for DatabaseName (or source name) then this should work for you.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
    (
    Col1 INT NOT NULL
    , Col2 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    , Col3 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    , DatabaseName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    )

INSERT INTO @T
(Col1, Col2, Col3, DatabaseName)
VALUES (1, 'EDTU', 'Value1', 'FirstDB')
    , (1, 'EDTP', 'Value1', 'FirstDB')
    , (1, 'Other', 'Value1', 'FirstDB')
    , (1, 'EDTU', 'Value5', 'SecondDB')

;WITH CTE_Source AS
    (
    SELECT S.Col2
        , S.Col3
        , S.DatabaseName
    FROM @T AS S
    )
SELECT DatabaseName
    , EDTU
    , EDTP
FROM CTE_Source AS S
    PIVOT (MAX(Col3) FOR Col2 IN (EDTU, EDTP)) AS P
```